# MyEther Wallet storing ICO tokens

Tags: tokens, myetherwallet

Should I move ERC Tokens off of MyEther Wallet or can I store them there?

Answer (score 1):

your ERC Tokens are stored in the smartcontract which generate them, there are like Ethers. however you sould keep your private key safe. With Myetherwallet you could backup your private key in order to user with another wallet.

Answer (score 1):

With a MEW you have full control over your private key. You can think of your private key as a mathemagical stamp that can be used to **sign** virtual "checks" written on the ERC20 contract's token.

ERC20 tokens are only stored in the contract that created them. The contract can generate virtual "checkbooks" for that token. The checks in the checkbook are not worth anything without a **signature** your private key can **sign** those checks.

Remember the ethereum network is only updated with **signed transactions** only private keys can **sign transactions.**

Also remember anyone who has your private key (or the list of 12-24 word seed) can **sign transactions**

Your private key has all the control. Your public key is basically like legal letter head, anyone can see it, but its also has no power without a **signature**.

My Ether Wallet does not have access to your account, it's just an interface for the network.